# Unescape HTML from list column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, calculated-column, xslt

I've got a multiline column in a list that contains HTML. When trying to use the field in SharePoint Designer 2010, it shows it as raw HTML, instead of rendering it. So using this syntax:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@MyColumn"/>
```

it produces this:

```
<div class="ExternalClass5F52DACEBDE7496CB9F6756AA44F91EA"><p>​</p> <table width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:1em"><tbody><tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default"><td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:40%">​<strong>Sunday - Wednesday</strong></td> <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1">​00:00 to 00:00</td></tr> <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default"><td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:40%"><strong>​Thursday </strong></td> <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​​00:00 to 00:00</td></tr></tbody></table>   <p> </p></div>
```

I've read about using calculated columns and JavaScript to render HTML correctly. However, for ease of development, is there a best practice we can follow to not have this happen or to wrap the XML in Designer in an Unescape() function of some type? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an attribute you add to xsl:value-of called "disable-output-escaping".

So change your line to look like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="@MyColumn" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: Easy when you know how! :)

Comment: Where should I add disable-output-escaping in a field? I don't have access to the underlying code of the form, but do have the ability to modify the fields. Is this an attribute I can add to a field to properly render the HTML returned from a multiline field?